# Android Java: Runnable running more than once per post? PostDelayed

Tags: java, android, runnable

I made a simple animation where OnTouch the animation = true, else = false.  I want to set the animation in a runnable so I can control how fast the animation runs, but when I use the runnable it runs about 50 times (I checked with log) before it delays.

```
final Runnable walkData = new Runnable()
{
    public void run(){
        try{    
        if(walkAnim==true)
            {
                ship1 = Bitmap.createBitmap(walkArray.get(walkNum),
                              0, 0, walkArray.get(walkNum).getWidth(), 
                              walkArray.get(walkNum).getHeight(), shipMatrix, true);
                walkNum++;
                if(walkNum>16)
                {
                    walkNum=0;
                }
            }
            if(walkAnim==false)
            {
                ship1 = Bitmap.createBitmap(shippick, 0, 0, shippick.getWidth(),
                        shippick.getHeight(), shipMatrix, true);
            }
            Log.d("TestTag", "#");
        handler3.postDelayed(this, 1000);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
};
```

I have 2 other runnables using handler and handler2, and they seem to run just fine.  I post the runnable in the same iniatiton class as my other posts too.

Tl;dr: runnable runs 50 times instead of 1 time per postDelayed. wtf?

Final note: I know there are a lot of questions that are relatively the same as this, but I would like to know whats the cause.  Thanks!

Comment: >"walkAnim==true" "walkAnim==false"
True Indian Style

Comment: lol i changed it from else to see if it changed but it didnt

Comment: You missed the point. There are boolean arithmetic operators in Java, for example `!`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't post the full code, I assume that you are starting your 'walkData' 'Runnable' from some sort of a onTouchListener. Touch listners, unlike click listener, are called in rapid succession until you stop touching them.

in order to fix it, in you onTouch event you need to check if the runner is already running and either not do anything, or cancel the current running 'walkData' and start a new one.

Comment: Sorry, the post is in the initialization of the class, and WalkAnim is true if touchDown

Comment: Also the class is a custom draw view if that matters

Comment: OMG sorry I had the post in 
    
    for(i=0;i<50;i++){
    }

Sorry! :|